Turn off sending verificaiton email when creating user
I am using firebase authentication in my react-native app developing.
When I create user using firebase authentication, firebase sends verification email automatically.
But I want firebase not to send verification email when creating user.
This is the code to create user.
try {
var data = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.account_email, this.state.account_password);
this.authData = data;

  // verification email
  // this.authData.user.sendEmailVerification();

} catch(error) {
  console.error("[SignUp] onPressSignup() -> error: ", error);

  if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
    Toast.show({
      type: 'error',
      text2: "Your email address is already in use.",
    });
  } else if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
    Toast.show({
      type: 'error',
      text2: "Your email address is invalid.",
    });
  } else {
    Toast.show({
      type: 'error',
      text2: error.message,
    });
  }
}

I also tried to use firebase admin sdk's createUser function.
// user
var userData = {
  email: data.email,
  password: data.password,
  emailVerified: true,
};

var userRecord = await getAuth().createUser(userData);
functions.logger.info("\tuserRecord: ", userRecord.toJSON());

Is there any way to turn off automatically sending verificaiton email?

"When I create user using firebase authentication, firebase sends verification email automatically" No it doesn't. It's your own code that triggers that by calling sendEmailVerification, although you seem to have disabled that in the code in the question.

I solved this finally.

I used firebase admin sdk to create user

When creating user, use random email(that is not real email but with correct email format, ex. 123234@123.com).

once created user, using getAuth().updateUser to change random email to real email.
try {
 // random email
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
 var randomEmail = random + "@123.com";
 functions.logger.info("\t\trandomEmail: " + randomEmail);

 // user
 var userData = {
   email: randomEmail,
   password: data.password,
   emailVerified: true,
 };

 var userRecord = await getAuth().createUser(userData);
 functions.logger.info("\tuserRecord: " + userRecord.toJSON());

 await getAuth().updateUser(userRecord.uid, {
   email: data.email,
   emailVerified: true,
 });

 return {
   success: true,
   docId: userRecord.uid,
 };    
} catch(error) {
 functions.logger.error("createUser() -> error: ", error);

 return {
   success: false,
   error: error.message,
 };
}



